# Reading .rpt files with R

Tags: database, r, crystal-reports

Is there a way to do this?  We have information coming off the database that has been organized into a standard spreadhseet-looking format.  For smaller data pulls, we can just convert the .rpt file to a .csv and load that in (whether it be to Excel, R, or whatever).

However, once we go past a few days of data, the file gets much too large to open and convert either to csv or to just a tab-delieated text file.  (A month of data is 10 gigs and 10 million lines).

Is there a way to directly read into .rpt files using R?  I've searched, but it doesn't seem to be a widely-addressed topic (as in, not at all), which doesn't give me too much hope.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Loading **any** gigundo file is going to cause difficulties. Start by looking thru the CRAN package list for the tools to handle big data.   Next: are these Crystal Reports files or generic "rpt" report files? the latter are pure text and cand be opened directly.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It can be opened directly, using a basic text editor (up until it hits the file size limitations of the editor, of course).

There are definitely going to be a different set of challenges once we are dealing with the ginormous files, but at this point, we ran a small-ish one (1 day) to see what was even possible.

I could just convert this, but I know that is not possible once it gets too large- unless someone knows of either a text editor that can open extremely large files, a standalone exe that can convert rpt to csv, or a way to read it directly into R.

Comment: Take a look at packages `bigmemory` and `ff`, then.

Comment: You can improve this question in several ways: First try including a small .rpt file, and show us what you expect the .csv to look like. Next, write some code that can generate an arbitrarily large .rpt file, in the format that you have. That way, we can make sure the code does what you want, and then we can benchmark various solutions. I suspect that a few UNIX tools would be best to preprocess the text before feeding it into R, but that is just a guess.